# Get tinymce input and alert() it

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am just building a form with multiple steps.
On step 3, I have a tinymce editor. On step 4 I want to generate a preview of the input from tinymce. I have problems, to get the the contents form the tinymce input box. This is my current code:

```
jQuery('#next_is_preview').click(function(){
alert(jQuery("#content_ifr").contents().find("#tinymce").html());
});
```

Currently it returns null. 
What could be the issue?

Comment: probably because the `jQuery("#content_ifr")` selection or `.find("#tinymce")` filter does not return any elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably safest to use the TinyMCE API to get the contents i.e.

```
alert(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
jQuery('#next_is_preview').click(function(){ 
    alert(("#tinymce").html()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the API and your editors id (you used 'content')

```
alert(tinyMCE.get('content').getContent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet is working for me! I used it to copy from a tinymce textarea to another one and your code did the trick perfectly:

```
$("#copyBtn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#spanish_ifr").contents().find("#tinymce").html($("#english_ifr").contents().find("#tinymce").html())));
});
```